# C Function redeclaration in Code no Error GCC/XC8

Tags: c, gcc, prototype, xc8

I have written some code to be used on an embedded system but with a Windows demo version.  In it, I accidently redeclared a function and would like to determine the effect of this and how to catch it in the future.

I have written the below (simplified version)

```
#include "external_file.h"

void vClear( void ){
   void vReset( void );  //This should have been vReset();
 }
```

- vReset, is already prototyped in external_file.h and defined in external_file.c
- Running on PIC (XC8 2.40 w-9) and Windows (GCC 12.2.0 C99 -Wextra -Wall)
- XC8 provides a warning: (520) function "_vReset" is never called
- GCC provides no warning/error
- This redeclaration seems to mask the correct function

Is it valid to declare a function within function body?
Is there a way to make GCC flag this as XC8 does?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. You seem to already know that that's a function declaration. Are you unsure about whether multiple function declarations are allowed? Or whether function declarations are allowed inside of a function? Or what scope the declaration of `vReset` applies to?

Comment: Specifically, the accidental declaration does not have a definition is this allowed?
Does this basically amount to a statement with no effect?
Is there a way to make GCC flag this?

Comment: You should [edit] your question to reflect that. Right now, I don't read your question as asking what happens when you declare a function without defining it. In fact, it looks like you say that `vReset` is defined in `external_file.c`

Comment: You can declare functions as often as you like — once is sufficient, but as long as all the declarations agree sufficiently, there isn't a problem with repetition.  In your `vClear()` function, you declare but do not call `vReset()`; that's a waste of the compiler's time, but isn't formally a bug that must be diagnosed by a compiler.

Comment: That all makes sense, thanks for the help.  I have modified the post with 2 clarifications.

Comment: It is valid to declare a function in the body of another function.  It isn't good practice, but it is valid.  Good practice says that if the function is used in other files, it should be declared in a header, and that header should be included in the source file that defines the function and in all the source files that use the function, and there is no need for a declaration inside a function.  If the function is only used in the current file (translation unit, aka TU), the function should be `static` (not visible outside the TU), and should be either declared or defined before it is used.